# Making Button from another layout clickable

Tags: android, button, layout, android-relativelayout

Am relatively new to android, and this is the issue am having, i have a main layout which i would call layout A and another which i will call B for the purpose of this question, i included layout B in layout A with a include tag, layout B serves as a header in layout A, but layout B comes with a button, this button is not clickable in layout A, Please how can i make this button from layout B clickable.on the click of the button it is suppose to start another activity. thank you for your response. i will wait here for a while for any other questions you might have.

Comment: Are you implementing onClickListener interface to your activity??

Comment: @Raja, which activity would this be please

Comment: The activity which has the button

Comment: Am not raja, i will do that and let you know what the out come is. Thank you so much

Comment: @ raja, i have tried this, but still the button doesn't launch, a new activity when i click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need to do to jump to second activity from your current activity.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
      {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);    

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);// id of your button in layout.xml

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
          public void onClick(View v)
          {
             Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
             CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
          }
        });

      }
```

Comment: @ raja, thank you for your quick response and effort, i will try this  now and get back to you

Comment: you are awesome! thank you so much for the answer, am grateful you took out time, to answer me, you are a blessing you need to see the smile on my face. THANK YOU SO MUCCCCHHHHHH!!!!!!!!!!!